# Use version catalog inside precompiled Gradle plugin

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-plugin, kotlin-gradle-plugin

I am converting my project with multiple modules to use [Precompiled Gradle Plugins](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:precompiled_plugins). This project also uses Gradle's version catalog (libs.versions.toml) where the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html#sec:sharing-catalogs) explicitly shows how to share it with the build.gradle.kts of the buildSrc directory, which works fine. But unfortunately this does not apply to the plugins themselves. Example:

**build-logic/settings.gradle.kts**

```
rootProject.name = "build-logic"

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    versionCatalogs {
        create("libs") {
            from(files("../gradle/libs.versions.toml"))
        }
    }
}
```

**build-logic/build.gradle.kts:**

```
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
    `kotlin-dsl-precompiled-script-plugins`
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(libs.plugins.kotlin.jvm) // works fine
}
```

**build-logic/src/main/kotlin/my-template.gradle.kts**

```
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm")
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(libs.kotlinx.serialization) // "Unresolved reference: libs"
}
```

Is it possible to reference "libs" inside `my-template.gradle.kts`?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there is an [open issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/15383) about this request and a workaround has been found. To use `libs` inside the precompiled plugin you have to add the following:

build-logic/build.gradle.kts

```
dependencies {
    implementation(files(libs.javaClass.superclass.protectionDomain.codeSource.location))
}
```

build-logic/src/main/kotlin/my-template.gradle.kts

```
import org.gradle.accessors.dm.LibrariesForLibs

val libs = the<LibrariesForLibs>()

dependencies {
    implementation(libs.kotlinx.serialization) // works now!
}
```

[Credit](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/15383#issuecomment-779893192)

Comment: Can it be used in the `plugins { }` block as well? Can't get it to work, getting `Unresolved reference`

Comment: As far as I know this does not work yet for the plugins block. Gradle documents it here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_convention_plugins.html#applying_an_external_plugin_in_precompiled_script_plugin